# Searching This Array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, sorting, arraylist

I'm trying to write a program that goes through an array and reads the array until it reaches -1 for example:

```
A[0]=1, A[1]=3, A[2]=-1, A[3]=3, A[4]=4
A = [1, 3, -1, 4]
```

this should return 4 because it took 4 steps to get to `A[2]` which has the number -1 in it

Please Help

Comment: By your logic, would it not return 3? -1 is encountered in the third array element.

Comment: are you supposed to use an array or a list?

Comment: @JoshEngelsma list=array

Comment: @BallPython Not in python... A `list` is different than an [`array`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html). The OP most likely meant `list`, though, as it's quite common for beginners to user them interchangeably.

Comment: @jme it's in fact the same. array just allows you to use very specific features from this C lib.

Comment: @BallPython But they aren't... They're *similar* in terms of API, but they aren't the same thing. `array`s must be homogenous in data type. They are more space efficient than `lists`, because they're a thin wrapper around C arrays. Most of the time, `list`s are the tools for the job, not `array`s.

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean `3`. It takes only three steps to reach `-1`

```
>>> A = [1,3,-1,3,4]
>>> A.index(-1)+1
3
```

OR

You could use `enumerate` function.

```
>>> for x,y in enumerate(A):
        if y ==  -1:
            print(x+1)


3
```

Answer (score 0):

I havent dabbled in python for a long time, but basically you are looking for a way to iterate through the array. (Forgive the syntax)

```
A = [1, 3, -1, 3, 4]
for i in range(len(A)):
    if A[i] == -1:
        print i + 1
        break
```

Comment: Thanks Josh, as i said, I haven't played in python in a while.

Comment: Don't use range(len(array)), in python we have enumerate.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it took 3 steps not 4. The best for that, use [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html).

```
a=[1,3,-1,3,4]
for index,value in enumerate(a,1):
    if value==-1:
        print (index)
```

In here `enumerate(a,1)` as you see we can decide which number to start. We wrote `1` because we are starting to count from `1`.